# Correct way to use onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to post data when user arrives my page. This works in chrome and explorer, and also firefox, but however, on firefox, it strangely only works if user closes the page. If they go back, or goes another site (by typing to address bar or whaever) it doesnt post the data. My question is, what is the correct way to use onbeforeunload to post data ?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {

      $.post("track.php", {
         async: false,
         ip: ip,
         referer: referer,
         clicks: kactane2,
         scrolls: kactane,
         time: time,
         refid: refid,
         country: country, 
      });

});
```

Comment: There is no correct way, if you're lucky the ajax call will happen before the browser has time to redirect, if you're not, it won't, and in IE it usually redirects before the data can be sent.

Comment: What should I do to be lucky ?

Comment: maybe returns string from onbeforeunload

Comment: @user198989 Because it does not and won't work as you expect. You would do best not using it all.

Comment: There is really nothing you can do to make your self more "lucky". Years ago a simple while loop could delay just long enough, but modern day browsers killed that.

Comment: I remember another question (can't find it at the moment) that wanted to track how long people stayed on a page, and would send that data via AJAX on the `beforeunload` event, but was running into the same problems (which resulted in the complete loss of data about some users for a given session). One of the better solutions was to periodically send the data so that the database would be at least mostly up to date. Perhaps you could implement periodic data posts, if that makes sense for your data.

Comment: The solution is to rethink what you're trying to do. Browsers don't do what you're asking them to do, the fundamental request/response architecture *doesn't work this way*. There is no good way to send a request when the browser leaves your site, nor should there be.

Comment: Looks like returning string could work on FF: http://jsfiddle.net/zTV5V/show/

Comment: You say `post data when user arrives`.  Why would you want to use `beforeunload`?

Comment: I agree with Rocket Hazmat,  You should be running this on $(document).ready(), not onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a good way because that is not how `onbeforeunload` was meant to be used.

The correct way to use `onbeforeunload` is to listen for this event and then unload any data or resources you might be using because the user is leaving the page.  You should not use it to try to start new things.  According to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#changes-2011-05-25) `showModalDialog()`, `alert()`, `confirm()` and `prompt()` are explicitly not allowed and the idea is to give you a moment to clean up any event handlers, web workers and other stuff cleanly.

If an event handler is defined then the user may be presented with a page that says `"Are you sure you want to leave?"` but for security reasons the form is generally not able to be customized, but it depends on the browser.

You will probably be better off setting the data in a cookie or something that can be done quickly and that is only occurring in the browser, then just look for that data on the next page load.