# Using onbeforeunload without dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to post data when a user leaves my page. I have finally managed to find a working solution, however, it shows a confirmation dialog when the user leaves. I have tried `return null;` but it didn't work. Is it possible to disable the dialog?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $.post("track.php", {
        async: false,
        refid: refid,
        country: country, 
        type: type,
    });

    return '';
}
```

Comment: Don't return anything?

Comment: You need to use return on window.onbeforeunload :(

Comment: Maybe there is a workaround, let me test it. I suppose your question is following this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169092/correct-way-to-use-onbeforeunload   correct?

Comment: This one works, but only issue is it pops a dialog, ok ? There are different questions.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

From the [Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to
>   confirm the page unload.

This means the return value of the handler must be `undefined` (not `''`, `false`, or `null`) in order to avoid triggering the confirmation prompt.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

  $.post("track.php", {
  ...
  });

  return undefined;
}
```

In javascript you can skip the return value altogether to get the same result.

In coffeescript with jquery it's something like

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', ->
    #put your cleanup code here
    undefined
  )
```

Comment: For information, the "beforeunload" event is not reliable for data manipulation. The primary goal was just to display an alert message before leaving the web page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed/11530896#comment92256676_11530896

Answer (score 13):

If you want to disable the dialog, please only write

`window.onbeforeunload = function() {
...
return;
}`

instead of

`window.onbeforeunload = function() {
...
return '';
}`.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Removing `return` statement worked for me also.

Answer (score 2):

Could you test this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (e.originalEvent) $.post("track.php", {
        async: false,
        refid: refid,
        country: country,
        type: type,
    });
    else $.get("", {
        async: false
    });
    $(this).trigger('beforeunload');
}
```

This will create many useless requests but should let your first request enough time to reach server.

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the solution, the bind beforeunload should be bind onbeforeunload.

Comment: you mean: $(window).bind('onbeforeunload',...) ???  Because using this shouldn't work at all. Anyway, if you got a correct workaround, please post it as answer.

Comment: It works. I have tried on firefox, chrome and  explorer. All worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a really simple trick to get this working with using

```
$(window).bind('onbeforeunload', function () {

$.post("track.php", {
async: false,
refid: refid,
country: country, 
type: type,
});

});
```

Comment: Ok, maybe you are using older version of jquery because now: <<Note that there is no longer 'on' in the event being bound. Using the previous onbeforeunload in later versions of jQuery will result in nothing happening.>>

Comment: I'm using the same approach put the post code won't trigger without return

Answer (score 1):

This is with react and typescript:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.onbeforeunload = (ev: any) => {
      ev.preventDefault()
      anotherMethod()
    }
  }, [])
```