# onbeforeunload event functioning

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have a requirement where when we close the tab or close the `browser` I need to perform some `processes`. When user will close the tab, there should be no `popup` getting displayed. I should be able to directly trigger the `Leave` button of the `popup`. The code which I am using sometimes work and sometimes not. Is it possible to close the tab or browser without popup or the `popup` is mandatory. Please advise. Below is my code :-

*Without Popup(sometimes work and sometimes not)*

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                             //debugger;
                             perform();
                         };
```

*//With this i get a popup which I don't want*

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
                        perform();
                          (e || window.event).returnValue = null;
                          return null;
                        });
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [`unload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event)?

Comment: replace `return null` with `undefined` as said in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29627642/9496199